# Exporting module in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have the following my custom module that successfully exports.

```
module.exports = function(callback) {

    var request = require("request")
    var url = "http://sheetsu.com/apis/94dc0db4"

    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {

        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

            callback(body)

        }
    })
```

Now if I try to change the way to export this as the following, I get 404 error.

```
var data = function(callback) {

    var request = require("request")
    var url = "http://sheetsu.com/apis/94dc0db4"

    request({
        url: url,
        json: true
    }, function (error, response, body) {

        if (!error && response.statusCode === 200) {

            callback(body)

        }
    })

}

module.exports = data;
```

What am I doing wrong?

**UPDATE**

This is the route index.js that renders the received data.

```
var data = require('../lib/data.js');

data(function(data) {
    router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
      res.render('index', { 
        title: 'Express', 
        data: data
      });
    });
});
```

And the error is at at /Users/xxxxx/Dev/Project/app.js:32:13

I haven't changed any other codes except how I changed the export part.

Comment: Get 404 error from what?  The two pieces of code would operate identically so you must have some other code that is causing a behavior difference.

Comment: Are you sure? There is no logical reason for that.

Comment: Not sure why this post is off-topic. Just trying to learn something here.
Please see my update for more detail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call your function inside the route, not vice a verca:

```
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
  data(function(d) {
      res.render('index', { 
         title: 'Express', 
         data: data
      });
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Calling my function outside the route worked with my previous methodology of wrapping my data.js within `module.exports = {}` So, I still don't understand why the function will need to be called inside the route in this case?

Comment: I don't know how this worked before as it's incorrect. You should first define all your routes and call actions inside them, otherwise it's not guaranteed that your route will be defined inside a callback